# CakePHP routing multilingual blog with canonical links

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, seo, canonical-link

I have the following routes set up on my CakePHP site

```
Router::connect('/:language/blog', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en', 'persist'=>array('language')));

Router::connect('/:language/blogue', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'fr', 'persist'=>array('language')));

Router::connect('/:language/blog/:post_id', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('language' => 'en', 'persist'=>array('language', 'post_id')));

Router::connect('/:language/blog/:post_id/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('language' => 'en', 'persist'=>array('language', 'post_id', 'slug')));

Router::connect('/:language/blogue/:post_id', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('language' => 'fr', 'persist'=>array('language', 'post_id')));

Router::connect('/:language/blogue/:post_id/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('language' => 'fr', 'persist'=>array('language', 'post_id', 'slug')));
```

Which gives me URLs like `/en/blog` or `/fr/blogue` Is there a way to remove the language from appearing in the URL and have it just display `/blog` or `/blogue` (but still persist the language param)?

If that's not possible I can probably live with keeping the language in the url however this next bit is really important. I have something like this in my `<head>`

```
echo '<link rel="canonical" href="'. Router::url($this->request->here true) .'">';
```

where I'd like to include a canonical URL for SEO. I'd like the canonical URL to be simply `/blog/123` but it is always showing as whatever the current url is ie. `/en/blog/123/article-slug` or `/fr/blogue/123/article-slug`. Does anyone know how I can get the desired behavior? (side question: does removing the slug part from the canonical url defeat the purpose of using friendly URLs for SEO?)

Comment: Read the article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching or http://blog.kdev.pl/2013/02/internacjonalizacja-statyczna-i.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing my routes to these

```
Router::connect('/blog', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index', 'language'=>'en'), array('persist'=>array('language')));
Router::connect('/blog/:post_id', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'language'=>'en'), array('persist'=>array('language', 'post_id')));
Router::connect('/blog/:post_id/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'language'=>'en'), array('persist'=>array('language', 'post_id', 'slug')));

Router::connect('/blogue', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index', 'language'=>'fr'), array('persist'=>array('language')));
Router::connect('/blogue/:post_id', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'language'=>'fr'), array('persist'=>array('language', 'post_id')));
Router::connect('/blogue/:post_id/:slug', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'language'=>'fr'), array('persist'=>array('language', 'post_id', 'slug')));
```

and in my Posts controller View action I added

```
$this->set('canonical', Router::url(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'view', 'post_id'=>$post['Post']['id'], 'language'=>'en')));
```

And in the `<head>` section of my layout file I added

```
if (!isset($canonical)) {
    $canonical = $this->request->here;
}
if ($canonical !== false) {
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="'. Router::url($canonical, true) .'">';
}
```

Comment: Consider this "If you have multiple language versions of a URL, each language page must identify all language versions, including itself." https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

Answer (score -1):

What about just removing the `:language` and setting it for each?:

```
Router::connect('/blogue/:post_id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('language' => 'fr', 'persist'=>array('post_id', 'slug')));

Router::connect('/blog/:post_id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('language' => 'en', 'persist'=>array('post_id', 'slug')));
```

Comment: If I remove the :language part then it doesn't do any language switching at all and doesn't match for reverse routing (my links automatically include the language param)